# Fedora 29 upgrading 1400 packages -- is it safe to shut down in the middle of the upgrade?

Tags: fedora, upgrade, dnf

Is it safe to stop this in the middle?  I am need to leave soon and have to shutdown my system ( I am working via USB at a public computer)

Answer (score 6):

Is it still downloading or is it actually applying the updates?

Once it starts to apply the updates then cancelling the command is not a good idea as it may be in the middle of installing packages that have dependencies that have not yet been updated.